# Android POST call getting Server 500 error using Retrofit

Tags: android-studio, post, android-developer-api

This seems like a really simple issue, but I cannot figure it out. The API I am calling works fine in Postman and form the iOS version of the App. Just Android is giving me a fit. It may be not enough coffee. I am using Android Studio on the latest updates.

API accepts a long URL as JSON body and returns a shortURL as string.

**Error Screenshot:**

[Android Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSMVK.png)

**POST Call:**

```
private void getShortURL() {
    //Get full url
    final String fullURL = Constants.SHARE_BASE_URI + urlParameters;

    //Convert URL to JSON formatted data
    Map<String,String> data = new HashMap<String,String>();
    data.put("URL",fullURL);
    String jsonData = new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(data,Map.class);

    //Call API and pass in JSON to get Short URL
    Call<ResponseBody> getDynamicLinkCall = RetrofitAdapter.getRetroInterface(Constants.BASE_URI).getDynamicLink_String(Constants.getTimestamp(),Constants.APPLICATION,"application/json", jsonData);

    getDynamicLinkCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            if (response == null ||  response.code() != Constants.SUCCESS) {
                //Share Short URL
                share(response.body().toString());
            }
            else
            {
                //If Short URl Failed share long URL
                share(fullURL);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            //If Short URl Failed share long URL
            share(fullURL);
        }
    });
}
```

**RetrofitInterface.java**

```
@POST("URLShortner")
Call<ResponseBody> getDynamicLink_String(@Header("TimeStamp") String timestamp, @Header("Application") String application, @Header("Content-Type") String contentType, @Body String jsonData);
```

**Postman Screenshot:**

[Screenshot from Postman showing Body settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHTTR.png)

**Retrofit Adapter Code:**

```
package com.company.appname.util;
import android.content.Context;
import com.company.appname.Constants;
import java.net.CookieHandler;
import java.net.CookieManager;
import java.net.CookiePolicy;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import okhttp3.CookieJar;
import okhttp3.JavaNetCookieJar;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.jackson.JacksonConverterFactory;

public class RetrofitAdapter {
    public static OkHttpClient okHttpClient;
    public static Context context;

public static RetrofitInterface getRetroInterface(String endPoint){
    return createRestAdapter(endPoint).create(RetrofitInterface.class);
}

public static Retrofit createRestAdapter(String endPoint){
    boolean isMobileAPI = false;

    //Check if the endpoint is the mobile api
    if(endPoint.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.MOBILE_SERVICE_BASE_URI)){
        isMobileAPI = true;
    }

    //Create a rest adapter
    return  new Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(createOkClient(isMobileAPI))
            .baseUrl(endPoint)
            .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
}

public static OkHttpClient createOkClient(boolean isMobileAPI){

    NextModel next = NextModel.getInstance();

    if(next.okClient == null || !isMobileAPI) {
        //Create ok http Client
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        //Set timeouts
        httpClient.readTimeout(Constants.TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        httpClient.connectTimeout(Constants.TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        CookieJar cookieJar = new PersistentCookieJar(new SetCookieCache(), new SharedPrefsCookiePersistor(context));

        //Add cookieJar to Http Client
        httpClient.cookieJar(cookieJar);

        //Create OkHttpClient
        okHttpClient = httpClient.build();

        return okHttpClient;
    }else{
        //Return already created okclient
        return next.okClient;
    }
}


public static OkHttpClient getOkClient() {
    return okHttpClient;
}

}
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Is this the only case where this happens? Or does it happen with other POSTs GETs as well? Can you post your RetrofitAdapter please?

Comment: This is the only case. That's what so frustrating. I will update the OP with the RetroFit Adapter.

Comment: We just stumbled upon the answer, posted it below. Thanks Luis!

Comment: Nice. It is weird though, how it worked with some Android versions but not with others. I'm glad you found the answer. Happy coding ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, we found the issue. We were missing the following line of code:

```
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"),jsonObject.toString());
```

This code went in before the POST call, and instead of POSTing jsonData, we post body, that fixed it. Wish Android Studio had given an error of some kind to hint at this.

**Full Method:**

```
private void getShortURL() {
    //Get full url
    final String fullURL = Constants.SHARE_BASE_URI + urlParams;

    //Convert URL to JSON formatted data
    Map<String,String> data = new HashMap<String,String>();
    data.put("LINK",fullURL);
    String jsonData = new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(data,Map.class);

    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), jsonData);

    //Call API and pass in JSON to get Short URL
    Call<String> getDynamicLinkCall = RetrofitAdapter.getRetroInterface(Constants.BASE_URI).getDynamicLink_String(Constants.getTimestamp(),Constants.APPLICATION,"application/json", body);

    getDynamicLinkCall.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
            if (response == null ||  response.code() != Constants.SUCCESS) {
                //Share Short URL
                share(response.body().toString());
            }
            else
            {
                //If Short URl Failed share long URL
                share(fullURL);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
            //If Short URl Failed share long URL
            share(fullURL);
        }
    });
}
```

**RetrofitINterface.java:**

```
@POST("URLShortner")
Call<String> getDynamicLink_String(@Header("TimeStamp") String timestamp, @Header("Application") String application, @Header("Content-Type") String contentType, @Body RequestBody jsonData);
```

Thanks All!